# Set Text on combobox while getting data

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm trying to display a default text in a `ComboBox` while I'm fetching data from a source, but it doesn't show anything.

```
<ComboBox  
         Grid.Row="1" 
         Grid.Column="2" 
         Text="Hepper"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Builds}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBuild}"
         DisplayMemberPath="VersionNo" 
         IsReadOnly="True" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedBuildEnable}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Width="180" 
         Height="30" 
         MinWidth="180" />
```

Comment: My guess would be that `Buids` is a list of a custom class which makes every item in your `ComboBox` an item of that class, and not a string. this is why `Hepper` won't show..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to set the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` Property instead of `ComboBox.Text`.

I prefer to show another TextBlock above the ComboBox to display a default text:

```
<!-- don't forget to define the converter in your resources -->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>    

<!-- your Control -->
<ComboBox  
     Grid.Row="1" 
     Grid.Column="2" 
     x:Name="ComboBoxElement"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Builds}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBuild}"
     DisplayMemberPath="VersionNo" 
     IsReadOnly="True" 
     IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedBuildEnable}" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Width="180" 
     Height="30" 
     MinWidth="180" />

<TextBlock 
      Grid.Row="1" 
      Grid.Column="2" 
      Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=ComboBoxElement, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
      IsHitTestVisible="False" 
      Text="Hepper" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="15,5" />
```

I guessed that your ComboBox becomes enabled if the data is fetched. Otherwise you have to use another binding for the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, the `ComboBox.Text` property

> Gets or sets the text of the currently selected item.

Therefore, you could temporarily add an item into your `ComboBox` with your required message, select it and then remove it before filling the `ComboBox` when your data arrives.